# Hidden crashed ship?

Tags: command-and-conquer-rivals

While swiping the ranked PVP menu to the end of the Tiberium League, I've found a rare crashed ship.

It can only be seen if you try to swipe to the maximum right side. I tried searching for related ships in the Tiberium Wars saga but but none of them looks like it. Is it an Scrin ship? What ship is this?

Also It is not interactible as far as I know.

[image: hidden crashed ship]

A clearer screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported by [these](https://www.reddit.com/r/cncrivals/comments/9ww1eb/crashed_ts_scrin_ship_spotted_in_cc_rivals_are/) [two](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandandconquer/comments/a7gl97/easter_egg_in_cc_rivals_tib_sun_crashed_alien_ufo/) Reddit threads, **it is a crashed Scrin ship**, that, according to the *r/cncrivals* community leader *Alex06*, has appeared with the - at that point - most recent update to Rivals (which [seems](https://www.apkmirror.com/uploads/?q=command-conquer-rivals) to be 1.2.0).

The same user mentions it is a throwback to Tiberian Sun, so I expect it should resemble this ship (but covered in snow):

[image: The mysterious crashed Scrin ship]
<sup>[source](https://cnc.fandom.com/wiki/Scrin_ship)</sup>

In Tiberian Sun, the ship had to be secured and defended by the GDI ([Mission 3 'Secure the Crash Site'](https://cnc.fandom.com/wiki/Secure_Crash_Site) / [Mission 4 'Defend the Crash Site'](https://cnc.fandom.com/wiki/Defend_Crash_Site)).

Answer (score 0):

I found a link on reddit. Apparently it's not an actual "hidden ship", but instead an easter egg. Apparently it's a crashed ship from the Tiberian Sun Mission 4, although i'm not quite certain.

(Sorry if this is late)

Another edit- From the comments that could be a crashed Scrin ship.

Comment: This is not a quality answer. You didn't provide the reddit link nor do you show us how this is related to Mission 4. And mission 4 for WHICH faction?